# Your project is being suspended for cryptocurrency mining in violation of our Terms of Service (GCP bug)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ethereum

today I got an email that my project was mining cryptocurrencies and the instance was blocked, but **no cryptocurrencies have ever been mined in the project.**

How does google cloud conclude that cryptocurrencies are mined in the project?

I deploy a project in the energy sector based on blockchain technology, but this is only a deployment - I only deploy a project based on ethereum, and I do not know how google claims that I violate the rules of using the cloud.

Anyone had a similar problem? The solution is in the *almost* production phase and changes at this stage will be costly.

Comment: What do you think **blockchain** and **ethereum** are with respect to crypto mining? 1) Contact Google Cloud for a waiver, Stack Overflow cannot help you. 2) Your use case is not supported by Google Cloud. Read the Supplemental Terms and Conditions clause 3.2: **Customer may not use the Services to engage in mining cryptocurrency.** https://cloud.google.com/terms/free-trial

Comment: I found out what process causes this problem. The process occurs when building an application (yarn build) and can be read as cryptocurrency mining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever network monitoring and heurestics Google Cloud applies, we cannot know, because it is their company internal information.

We cannot know either how you violated Google Cloud rules and thus this question and the matter is strictly between you and Google. We are not starting to guess what stuff you run on your servers and so on.

If Google Cloud support is unhelpful, just use some more customer friendly cloud service provider and close your account with them. Generally, your negotiation power resolving issues like this with Google is zero so there is nothing can you do.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've already written to the google team, they've been helpful in the past.

In the meantime, however, I need to analyze other fallback options.